# Mongoose MongoDB Objects undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I've run into a strange issue. I've started to use MongoDB and it's most likely me doing something terrible wrong.

I have the following models setup:

```
var cartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    productline:  [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Productline' }]
});

var productlineSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    cart: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Cart' },
    product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'products' },
    quantity: Number
});
```

Initially the Cart is setup with an empty array when the User registers, but then we add Productline objects to it later (which works since I can see data in there in my GUI.).

I'm trying to read the name value which is intended to be reached from **cart -> productline -> product**

```
for (var i=0; i < cartModel.productline.length; i++) {
    console.log(cartModel.productline[i].product.name);
}
```

But getting *TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined* on exactly that line, which means that **product == "undefined"**.

However, when I'm checking in my MongoDB with MongoDB Compass, then I can see that there is infact a connection between them, and the id's looks accurate as far as I can tell, so it should be able to read it.

So either I'm trying to reach the values in the wrong way, `cartModel.productline[0].product.name`.

Or my code doesn't realize that the object has been updated, which is strange since I even made sure to use `Cart.findOne(query, function(err, cartModel) { ... }` to be sure I get a fresh one from the database.

Anyone has any ideas? I'll be glad to post some more code if needed, I just tried to find the most relevant parts above, but I might be missing something somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve this by myself. For people who are having problems with nested objects, I recommend you looking into the mongoose-deep-populate plugin: https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate

It helped me out a lot, and my final query ended up like this:

```
Cart.findOne({_id: cart}).deepPopulate('productline.product').exec(function (err, docs) {
    // docs is JSON data which can be used to reach the nested data.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered similar error recently

#### Demo

When I use: `.populate('productline')`

```
Cart.findOne({_id: cart}).populate('productline').exec(function(err, docs) {
   /* docs.productline items represent the correct model but their 
      fields are undefined except the `_id` */
})
```

#### Solution

When I use: `.populate({path: 'productline'})`

```
Cart.findOne({_id: cart}).populate({path: 'productline'}).exec(function(err, docs) {
   /* docs.productline items represent the correct model with all properties
      fetched with the correct values */
})
```

#### Other solution

This example from http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html helped me

```
Story
    .find(...)
    .populate({
        path: 'fans',
        match: { age: { $gte: 21 }},
        select: 'name -_id', /* populates only these fields in the `fans` collection */
        options: { limit: 5 }
    })
    .exec()
```